# Pageref the "List of..."

Tags: cross-referencing, indexing

In my thesis I have a "writing conventions" at the very beginning. There it is explained how abbreviations are introduced. In this explanation, I would like to say

> A list of abbreviations can be found on page xxx

How can I `pageref` this index ? Thank you! Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

You can find the list of abbreviations at \pageref~{???}.

\appendix
\appendixpage
\chapter{myAppendix}

\backmatter
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Sure, I always do, just forgotten it for the MWE :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put something like `\label{abbreviations}` where your abbreviations appear and then use `\pageref{abbreviations}` where you want to print the page number.